# Parsing a String based on '$', as being used string seperator and may be used as the part of the value

Tags: java

1. "$1200-$2000$amol"  -->{$1200-$2000, amol}.
2. "amol$$1200-$2000"  -->{amol,$1200-$2000}.
3. "amol$1200-2000"    -->{amol,1200-2000}.
4. "amol$$1200-$2000$patare" -->{amol,$1200-$2000,patare}.
5. "amol$$1200-$2000$patare$$12-$20" -->{amol,$1200-$2000,patare,$12-$20}.

Here, I am looking for the logic which will parse the string (left hand side) and result in a vector(right hand side). '$' is used as a seperator and '$' may be the part of the value for eg. second pattern "amol$$1200-$2000" here $ is seperator between "amol" and "$1200-$2000" as well as '$' is the part of value "$1200-$2000".

```
private Vector getTockensForLovValue(String lovValue) //...where lovValue is the string to be parsed {
int beginIndex = 0; Vector vector = new Vector();

    while (beginIndex < lovValue.length())
    {
        int dollarIndex = lovValue.indexOf("$", beginIndex);
        if (dollarIndex != -1)
        {
            String s1 = lovValue.substring(beginIndex, dollarIndex);
            vector.add(s1);
            beginIndex = dollarIndex + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            vector.add(lovValue.substring(beginIndex));
            beginIndex = lovValue.length();
        }

    }

   return vector;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything to solve this?

Comment: Yes, I tried. I wrote a programme shared below..........

Comment: how do you identify whether a dollar is payload or separator?

Comment: for pattern like amol$$1200-$2000..we can get count of '$' if its two then we can say that here it is acting as a seperator

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** The answer has been updated with an extended regex to also map `amol$$1200$patare` to `{amol,$1200,patare}` as request in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37405704/5221149#comment62323275_37406432).

You can use a regular expression to do this:

```
\$\d+(?:-\$\d+)?(?=\$|$)|[^$]+|(?<=^|\$)(?=\$|$)
```

It says: First try to match `$99-$99` or `$99`. The match must be followed by `$` or end-of-string.
If that fails, match a sequence of any character that is not `$`.
Also match the empty string between two `$` or before leading `$` or after trailing `$`.

When specified in a Java string literal, double the `\`.

```java
private static List<String> parse(String input) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\$\\d+(?:-\\$\\d+)?(?=\\$|$)|[^$]+|(?<=^|\\$)(?=\\$|$)");
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Matcher m = p.matcher(input); m.find(); )
        list.add(m.group());
    return list;
}
```

See [regex101 for demo](https://regex101.com/r/lF6kX2/4).

**TEST**

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    test("$1200-$2000$amol");
    test("amol$$1200-$2000");
    test("amol$1200-2000");
    test("amol$$1200-$2000$patare");
    test("amol$$1200-$2000$patare$$12-$20");
    test("amol$$1200$patare");
    test("$$$1200$$");
    test("$$$1200x$$");
}
private static void test(String input) {
    System.out.println(input + " --> " + parse(input));
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
$1200-$2000$amol --> [$1200-$2000, amol]
amol$$1200-$2000 --> [amol, $1200-$2000]
amol$1200-2000 --> [amol, 1200-2000]
amol$$1200-$2000$patare --> [amol, $1200-$2000, patare]
amol$$1200-$2000$patare$$12-$20 --> [amol, $1200-$2000, patare, $12-$20]
amol$$1200$patare --> [amol, $1200, patare]
$$$1200$$ --> [, , $1200, , ]
$$$1200x$$ --> [, , , 1200x, , ]
```

Comment: test("amol$$1200$patare"); for this pattern I am expecting value as {amol,$1200,patare}

Comment: we can use pattern as         Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\$\\d+-\\$\\d+|\\$\\d+|[^$|]+"); which will cover the case which I have mentioned above.